# Use const to create a write once variable?

Tags: c

In C, is there a way to have a static U32 that can be initialised early at runtime; but that appears to the rest of the code as a const?

My attempt:

```
static const U32 writeOnce = 0;

void init( U32 initVal ) {
    *(U32*)writeOnce = initVal;
}
```

The syntax is accepted; but by runtime, the otherwise readonly uses of `writeOnce` have been embeded directly into the opcodes and the variable optimised away.

I was thinking maybe a extern const might work; but can't wrap my brain around how.

The basic need to to make the read references to the variable as amenable to optimisation as possible; once the value has been set at runtime.

Ie. If the value is used several times with a function, some way to tell the compiler that it only need read the value from memory once.

Hm. Now I spelt it out; I think I'm going to be out of luck (non-volatile doesn't exist:), but I ask the question anyway and see what comes.

Cheers, Buk.

Comment: There's no general portable mechanism, no, but you can sort-of hint at it by manually caching variables, judicious use of static/inline allowing the compiler to see what is reachable through where, and `restrict` to disprove pointer aliasing. Once in a blue moon I've gone as far as using #pragmas (MSVC's `__assume` for instance) to give even more heavy-handed hints to an optimizer acting up.

Comment: __restrict only applies to pointer vars. As the value is 32-bit and pointers are 64-bit on these systems; any saving that might accrue from mis-typing the value as a pointer would be negated by the need to fetch twice as much and then truncate it.

Comment: And I cannot see any way to use __assume() for this? How do you say assume( this var won't change)? (And how annoying you can't use paras in comments!)

Comment: The idea is that `restrict` may be useful as a hint even if the actual pointer access itself ends up optimized out, e.g. if any other code takes the address of writeOnce and the compiler couldn't otherwise figure out that an indirect write in your innerloop won't alias it. As for `__assume` you can use it to make a local copy of the variable assuming `writeOnce == localWriteOnce` at the site of each reference, thereby potentially allowing the compiler to optimize out the local copy if it isn't need.

Comment: " even if the actual pointer " Its not a pointer. And adding an __Assume and a local var to every function isn't on. (T'was nice to learn about restrict though :)

Comment: Indeed, but if you take out a restricted pointer to `writeOnce` then you've made a promise to the compiler that no other writes through pointers might touch it. The optimizer is then free to drop the physical pointer and decide on whether or not to cache the variable. Naturally is the type of hand-holding you would normally only perform for critical innerloops to coax the compiler into generating the assembly code you want, not something to litter the your business logic with.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can see to help the compiler in this regard is to use a local constant which is initialised from a non-const somehow, e.g.

```
uint32_t gParam;

void init()
{
    gParam = some_value;
}

void foo()
{
    const uint32_t kParam = gParam;

    // ... loops/function calls involving const kParam
}
```

I'm not entirely convinced that this will help with optimisation but it might be worth a try.

Comment: This seems like way to go. In my experience, compilers are a lot better at optimizing locals than globals.

Comment: Yes, globals are problematic because it's difficult/impossible for the compiler to know whether they will be modified, e.g. via an aliased pointer. Yet another reason to avoid globals!

Comment: The write-once global is used by many functions, mostly written by other people. Necessitating that they keep a local copy isn't really an option.

Comment: Depending on the structure of your code and APIs, you could cache kParam once in a calling function, e.g. `main()`, and then pass it as a const parameter to any functions that need it. Hiding the global somewhere would prevent functions from accessing it directly and force people to use the const parameter. Of course this is annoying if you have a lot of existing function signatures to change, so it may not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to control write access.

```
U32 writeOnce = 0;  // Value reported before it is written once during runtime.

void init( U32 initVal ) {
  static bool writeOnceFlag = 0;
  if (writeOnceFlag == 0) {
    writeOnceFlag = 1;
    writeOnce = initVal;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not to prevent me from writing to it a second time; The problem is to tell the compiler that it will never be written to a second time. This so that the compiler can assume it is safe to cache the value in a register and not re-read it from memory every time it is referenced.